# How do we keep specific dimension unchanged while reshaping in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a huge (N*20) matrix where every 5 rows is a valid sample, ie. every (5*20) matrix. I'm trying to reshape it into a (N/5,1,20,5) matrix where the dimension 20 is kept unchanged. I could do it in tensroflow using keep_dim, but how can I achieve this in numpy?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your array and output

Answer (score 3):

Reshape and then swap the axes around:

```
 arr1 = arr.reshape(N/5,5,1,20)
 arr2 = arr1.transpose(0,2,3,1)
```

for example

```
In [476]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(6,4)
In [477]: arr
Out[477]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])
In [478]: arr1 = arr.reshape(2,3,1,4)
In [479]: arr2 = arr1.transpose(0,2,3,1)
In [480]: arr2.shape
Out[480]: (2, 1, 4, 3)
In [482]: arr2
Out[482]: 
array([[[[ 0,  4,  8],
         [ 1,  5,  9],
         [ 2,  6, 10],
         [ 3,  7, 11]]],


       [[[12, 16, 20],
         [13, 17, 21],
         [14, 18, 22],
         [15, 19, 23]]]])
```